# Moving common project properties to global Gradle project in Android Studio

Tags: android

I have moved my ADT android project to Android Studio. Now I have a project with 2 modules. Each module has a build.gradle file, where it defines

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.3'

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}
```

I want to move this part to my project's build.gralde file so that it looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'android'


// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.3'

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

However, if I remove compileSdkVersion from module gradle files, I get gradle compilation error that this property is missing. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to move

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.3'

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}
```

Here Is an example of how I have it setup https://github.com/pieces029/test-project

Comment: Also, don't put an `android` block or `apply plugin` statement in your top-level build file. That will cause errors because it will look for an Android module at the top level that isn't there.

Comment: so, what should be the complete top-level build file? Could you please output it here?

Comment: This is similar to the problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420391/how-to-disable-lint-abortonerror-in-android-gradle-plugin-from-top-level-of-mult

Answer (score 0):

After doing a bit of research and quite a bit of trial and error, here is what I've done inside my Android project structure to define and share the Android build configuration across all of my projects.

My root project is a typical Android app with several activities. It has one child Android project that uses a nearly identical Android build configuration. My projects use the following directory structure:

```
root - builds an APK
  |
  +-- child - builds another APK
```

Inside root/build.gradle, I define the following to configure my shared Android build configuration. It uses properties from ext that are defined earlier in build.gradle. The ext block is also included below. The key is to put `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` at or near the top of `allprojects{}`.

```
ext {
    androidBuildToolsVersion = '21.1.1'
    androidCompileSdkVersion = 21
    androidMinSdkVersion = 17
    androidTargetSdkVersion = 21
    languageLevel = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

allprojects {
    // Build time plugins go here
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    // Android build tools version
    android.buildToolsVersion androidBuildToolsVersion
    // Android compilation target
    android.compileSdkVersion androidCompileSdkVersion

    // Configure AndroidManifest.xml
    android.defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.root"
        minSdkVersion androidMinSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion androidTargetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }

    // Rename the APK's using this format: <project name>-<DEBUG|RELEASE>-<version>.apk
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def oldFile = output.outputFile
            if(oldFile != null && oldFile.name.endsWith('.apk')) {
                def newFilename = "${project.name}-${variant.buildType.name.toUpperCase()}-${getAppVersionName()}"
                newFilename += ".apk"
                output.outputFile = new File(oldFile.parentFile, newFilename)
            }
        }
    }

    // Set the Android lint options
    android.lintOptions {
        // Abort the build if a lint error occurs
        abortOnError true
        // Disable warning for old gradle dependencies
        disable 'GradleDependency'
        // Disable the invalid package rule caused by ORMLite
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        // Disable Typography warnings
        disable 'TypographyDashes'
        disable 'TypographyFractions'
        // Disable LabelFor EditText warnings
        disable 'LabelFor'
        // Disable IconLauncherShape
        disable 'IconLauncherShape'
        // Disable warning for missing icon density folder (xxxhdpi)
        disable 'IconMissingDensityFolder'
    }

    // Set the Java language level
    android.compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility languageLevel
        targetCompatibility languageLevel
    }

    // Exclude the potential duplicate files contained inside open source libraries
    android.packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

    // APK signing configuration
    android.signingConfigs {
        MobileApp {
            storeFile file("StoreFile.jks")
            storePassword "********"
            keyAlias "MobileAppKey"
            keyPassword "********"
        }
    }

    // Build types
    android.buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig android.signingConfigs.MobileApp
        }
        release {
            signingConfig android.signingConfigs.MobileApp
        }
    }
}
```

root/settings.gradle contains this to build the child project:

```
include ':ChildProject'
```

Using the above inside my root project allows build.gradle inside my child project to be as simple as this. Anything not defined in the child project is picked up from the root project.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.child"
    }
}
```