# How to disable lint abortOnError in Android Gradle Plugin from top level of multi project directory

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have a top level Android Gradle project. There are multiple subprojects nested below this projects (sometimes they are 2 level deep) i.e:

```
top level project
   |
project1

vendor libraries
      |
     lib1

     lib2
```

lint is aborting my build in some of the libraries projects. I can edit each individual library project's `build.gradle` to fix the problem with

```
android {
   lintOptions {
      abortOnError false
   }
}
```

However, I would prefer the following code in the top level `build.gradle` script:

```
subprojects {

    afterEvaluate {
        if (getPlugins().hasPlugin('android') ||
            getPlugins().hasPlugin('android-library')) {

            println name // for debugging

            android {
                lintOptions {
                    abortOnError false
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The conditional statement makes sure to hook only into projects with an android plugin. I could only get this to work using afterEvaluate. However, my build is still failing on lint errors.

Does anyone have have a clean solution to inject these settings from the top level?

UPDATE:

Rearranging the subprojects and afterEvaluate or using allprojects still gives the same following kind of error:

```
7: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':3rdparty:OrmLiteQueryBuilder:lint'.
> [Ljava/util/HashMap$Entry;

* Try:    
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
==============================================================================

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 40.528 secs
```

Stacktrace:

```
7: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':3rdparty:OrmLiteQueryBuilder:lint'.
> [Ljava/util/HashMap$Entry;

* Try:    
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':3rdparty:OrmLiteQueryBuilder:lint'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:286)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Ljava/util/HashMap$Entry;
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.LintOptionsImpl$1.$getStaticMetaClass(LintOptionsImpl.groovy)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.LintOptionsImpl$1.<init>(LintOptionsImpl.groovy)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.LintOptionsImpl.syncTo(LintOptionsImpl.groovy:450)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.LintOptionsImpl$syncTo.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Lint.lintAllVariants(Lint.groovy:105)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Lint$lintAllVariants.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Lint.lint(Lint.groovy:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:212)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:201)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:530)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:513)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.util.HashMap$Entry
        ... 28 more

==============================================================================

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2 mins 20.757 secs
```

I can run `gradle build` successfully with the `-x lint` option but want to build without using the commandline options.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Perhaps try `allprojects` instead of `subprojects`, or `gradle.projectsEvaluated {}` instead of `subprojects { afterEvaluate {} }`. Also double-check that the build is still aborting due to (and not just printing) the lint errors.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser Appreciate the response. Tried both those combinations and still getting the same messages above.

Comment: This looks more like a fatal error executing the lint task, rather than a lint error. Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser there is a Java Class Def not found in the stacktrace. It's happening with six other libraries in the same way...

Comment: I suggest to report this at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list.

Comment: Thanks @PeterNiederwieser. Submitted: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72361

Answer (score 19):

I too faced a similar situation, but instead of just modifying the DSL directly, I called **configure** on it instead:

```
configure(android.lintOptions) {
    abortOnError false
}
```

As a result, I was able to disable **abortOnError** for my desired subprojects. Bottom line, your **subproject** block should look like this:

```
subprojects {

    afterEvaluate {
        if (getPlugins().hasPlugin('android') ||
            getPlugins().hasPlugin('android-library')) {

            println name // for debugging

            configure(android.lintOptions) {
                abortOnError false
            }
        }

    }
}
```