# React-Native: gradlew build yields :react-native-fbsdk:lint error "libraries must use the exact same version"

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, facebook-android-sdk

I'm running `./gradlew build` after adding facebook-android-sdk and I'm getting the following error. This is both on Windows and Mac, with Gradle 4.10.1.

```
> Task :react-native-fbsdk:lint
Ran lint on variant debug: 19 issues found
Ran lint on variant release: 19 issues found
Wrote HTML report to file:///C:/Foo/Bar/src/ReactNative/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/build/reports/lint-results.html
Wrote XML report to file:///C:/Foo/Bar/src/ReactNative/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/build/reports/lint-results.xml

> Task :react-native-fbsdk:lint FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-fbsdk:lint'.
> Lint found errors in the project; aborting build.

  Fix the issues identified by lint, or add the following to your build script to proceed with errors:
  ...
  android {
      lintOptions {
          abortOnError false
      }
  }
  ...

  Errors found:

  C:\Foo\Bar\src\ReactNative\node_modules\react-native-fbsdk\android\build.gradle: Error: All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0, 27.0.2. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2 [GradleCompatible]
```

Specifically, there's a compatibility issue between `com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0` and `com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2`.  Others have fixed similar issues by changing this line in build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
```

...to something like this:

```
implementation('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'cardview-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'customtabs'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-core-utils'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: ':animated-vector-drawable'
}

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

When I look at dependencies, they seem to be resolved correctly to 28.0.0, 
not 27.0.2 as indicated in the error:

```
./gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath
=> 
// ...
+--- com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.40.0
|    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.40.0
|    |    +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0
|    |    |    +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|    |    |    \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-applinks:1.4.0
|    |    |         \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2 -> 28.0.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.2 -> 28.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.40.0
|    |    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.40.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2 -> 28.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2 -> 28.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2 -> 28.0.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.2 -> 28.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:interpolator:28.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:collections:28.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0
```

Any idea what is going on here?

*edit*
Other things that don't work:

- adding the lintOptions to `build.gradle` as suggested in the error message has no effect.
- clearing the `$HOME/.gradle` cache and the `ReactNative/android/.gradle` cache
- Upgrading to gradle 4.10.3
- adding `disable "GradleDependency"` in `lintOptions`
- flagging lines with `//noinspection GradleDependency`
- `lintOptions.tasks.lint.enabled = false`

Comment: You can disable lint as suggested and see if you encouter any problems

Comment: @user1209216 I mentioned at the end that adding the suggested lines to build.gradle seems to have no effect.

Comment: I assume you added to module level build.gradle. Also try to include `ignoreWarnings true`. There should not be Lint error if you add it

Comment: @user1209216 Yes, I'm puzzled because I've added those lintOptions to `app/build.gradle` and it seems to have no effect.  I also tried `disable "GradleDependency"` to linkOptions but it also does nothing.  Also tried flagging lines with `//noinspection GradleDependency`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know React. Maybe it adds something else I don't know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to disable the error in lint if I put it in `app/build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
    // ...
    afterEvaluate {
        if (getPlugins().hasPlugin('android') ||
            getPlugins().hasPlugin('android-library')) {

            println name // for debugging

            configure(android.lintOptions) {
                 abortOnError false
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Source: [How to disable lint abortOnError in Android Gradle Plugin from top level of multi project directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420391/how-to-disable-lint-abortonerror-in-android-gradle-plugin-from-top-level-of-mult#answer-25149514)